# Mysql horizontalizing grouping

Tags: mysql, query, table, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that essentially has rows with:

```
sessionId
date/time
event
```

event can be (to make it simple, "start" and "end")

The same sessionId however can be reused, so, simply I have

```
sessionId     datetime                event
AAAAA         2020-01-01 11:30:00     start
AAAAA         2020-01-01 12:20:00     end
AAAAA         2020-01-01 14:22:00     start
AAAAA         2020-01-01 14:30:00     end
BBBBB         2020-01-02 14:22:00     start
BBBBB         2020-01-02 14:42:00     end
CCCCC ...etc ...
```

I need to convert it to:

```
SessionId     StartTime              duration
AAAAA         2020-01-01 11:30:00     00:50:00
AAAAA         2020-01-01 14:22:00     00:08:00
BBBBB         2020-01-02 14:22:00     00:20:00
```

Is there any way I can do this with an sql query or do I have to do it in code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: You should also add which version of mysql you use

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.sessionId, t1.dt StartTime, TIMEDIFF(t2.dt, t1.dt) duration
FROM src t1
JOIN src t2 ON t1.event = 'start'
           AND t2.event = 'end'
           AND t1.sessionId = t2.sessionId
           AND t1.dt < t2.dt
           AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                            FROM src t3
                            WHERE t3.sessionId = t1.sessionId
                              AND t1.dt < t3.dt
                              AND t3.dt < t2.dt );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0ecc8ee2bede6a65b0ef037b7eab6b7f)

Comment: See the added tag for improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, it can be done also with analytic functions. In the last versions of MySQL, they also exist.

```
create table T (
  sessionId varchar(20),
  datetime date,
  event varchar (10) );


Insert into T
 Values ('aa', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:02:41', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'start');
Insert into T
 Values ('aa', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:03:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'end');
Insert into T
 Values ('bb', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:03:22', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'start');
Insert into T
 Values ('bb', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:03:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'end');
Insert into T
 Values ('aa', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:03:54', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'start');
Insert into T
 Values ('aa', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:04:27', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'end');
Insert into T
 Values ('bb', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:04:48', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'start');
Insert into T
 Values ('bb', TO_DATE('21/04/2020 17:05:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'start');
COMMIT;

select * from T;  

SESSIONID      DATETIME            EVENT
-------------- ------------------- ----------
aa             21.04.2020 17:02:41 start
aa             21.04.2020 17:03:01 end
bb             21.04.2020 17:03:22 start
bb             21.04.2020 17:03:37 end
aa             21.04.2020 17:03:54 start
aa             21.04.2020 17:04:27 end
bb             21.04.2020 17:04:48 start
bb             21.04.2020 17:05:04 start
```

Usually, not all sessions will have an "end" event, some of them can end up abnormally, or some will not finish yet.

So in my example data, sessionid="bb" has two rows with only "start".

```
select sessionid, start_time,
       case when next_event = 'end' then end_time end AS end_time
  from (  
select sessionid, datetime start_time,
       lead(datetime) over (partition by sessionid order by datetime) end_time,
       lead(event) over (partition by sessionid order by datetime) next_event,  
       event
  from t   )
where event = 'start'  ; 

SESSIONID       START_TIME          END_TIME
--------------- ------------------- -------------------
aa              21.04.2020 17:02:41 21.04.2020 17:03:01
aa              21.04.2020 17:03:54 21.04.2020 17:04:27
bb              21.04.2020 17:03:22 21.04.2020 17:03:37
bb              21.04.2020 17:04:48
bb              21.04.2020 17:05:04
```

Comment: Eduard, thank you so much for your answer! I will try implementing immediately.
One clarification: in my example I simplified things, the actual table has many events, but I am only interested in the start and end events. Does this change things much?

Comment: Also, many sessions may start and end (i.e. bb could start before aaa ends), so I need to first sort them by sessoinid, time

Comment: unfortunately our version of mysql does not have the LEAD function :(